# Block Diagonalization related to Direct Sum and Single Eigenvalue?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, block-matrices

I'm just a beginner in Linear Algebra, and I've proved myself the following:

> A matrix $A^{n \times n}$ is block diagonalizable if and only if the base field $F^n$ can be divided into at least two subspaces, whose direct sum is $F^n$ and each being $A$ invariant.

Here, I removed the trivial case where every matrix can be seen as a single block diagonalized matrix. Surprising to me, I've learned that if the base field $F$ is algebraically closed and the given matrix has at least two distinct eigenvalues, then the matrix is block diagonalizable, using the theory of generalized eigenspaces.

I have two questions:

> 1. It follows that every algebraically closed field can be divided into at least two subspaces whose direct sum is $F^n$ and each being $A$ invariant if $A$ has at least two eigenvalues. What if the base field is not closed? Is there any simple counter-example(i.e. the base field is not closed and the matrix isn't block diagonalizable even though it has at least two distinct eigenvalues)?
> 2. What if the given matrix in the closed field has only one eigenvalue? I've conjectured that that matrix is block diagonalizable if and only if $F^n$=$N(A-\lambda I)+Col(A-\lambda I)$ where $N(A)$ is the nullspace, $Col(A)$ is the column space, $\lambda$ being the eigenvalue, $+$ here means direct sum. I counln't find any counter-example of this hypothesis. Any other elegant if and only if conditions for single eigenvalued matrix?